# MySQL: LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

Hello I have 2 tables:

**Events (idEvent, eventName)**

and

**Registrations(idRegistration, idEvent, idPerson)**

People register to events and I store their idPerson. Now let's say, we have 2 events (event1 and event2). I am person with id = 1 and I want to see all events and columns that will say me, if I am registered.

I mean output like :

```
idEvent  eventName  IamRegistered
1        event1     yes
2        event2     no
```

How can I write a query from these two tables to see similiar output?

PS: I know SQL syntax but can't figure it out, something with left join probably

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct, it is a left join. The CASE expression outputs Yes or No depending upon if a matching record was found.

```
SELECT e.idEvent, e.EventName, (CASE r.idEvent WHEN NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS IsRegistered FROM Events e
  LEFT JOIN Registrations r ON r.idEvent=e.idEvent AND r.idPerson=1
```

It's important to have the idPerson=1 check in the JOIN clause rather than the Where clause, otherwise events that person 1 is not registred for will not be displayed.

Comment: why do you check if registration's idEvent is null? Once registration is made it always belongs to some event..

It's like : We have events and people register to them. So f.e. 1 event - 100 registrations (from 300 people let's say)

Comment: r.idEvent (and all of r's fields) is null when there is no matching registration for person 1. (When there is no matching r.idEvent=e.idEvent and r.idPerson = 1).

Comment: I get always NO, even if I change conditioon to WHEN NULL

Comment: You may need to write `WHEN IS NOT NULL`. Alternatively try `IF (r.isEvent IS NULL, 'No', 'Yes')` instead of the `CASE...END`.